# Magento 1.9.x - Compiler Error after install Extension

Tags: category, fatal-error, compiler, solr, compilation

I tried a new extension for Magento Community (https://github.com/integer-net/solr-magento1) , after is produce many errors I deleted all the files.

Now, its cause error when Magento-Compiler is turned on, with an other extension and just on admin/categories page.

***Following ERROR :***

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php' (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/includes/src:.:/opt/plesk/php/5.5/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/includes/src/Vishwasnature_Editableproduct_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tabs.php on line 34
```

I tried already to clear and re-compile, but is doesnt help. Before I tried the solr extension, everything was normal.

Update: Tried also delete all database entries

How can I fix this? I tried several solutions from the deep internet.

Comment: have you installed extension during  compiler enable state ?

Comment: Yes, compiler was enabled

Comment: thats why u facing, when you install any extension make sure your compiler disabled

Comment: And what I need to do now? compiler clear command doesnt helped

Comment: i have added the answer try it, and marked ticked if it worked

Answer (score 0):

- As per Magento, When a compiler is enabled on system then magento 
  take it all enable modules class's and put in "includes/src".Thus make 
  site faster in loaded time.
- On your case, you have removed the files from the modules but not
  from the compiled files ("includes/src") thats why you faced this
  problem.
- Remove the modules files from "includes/src" and disable the
  compiler. After that you  can enable the compiler

Comment: I tired now, for be sure, i renamed src folder and recompile all files. Its not helped, i get same error message :(

Comment: disable compiler, remove the files from "include/src", clear the cache and session and try

Comment: I did now, multiple times, cleared everything but is still give same error I dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deactivate the compiler for just some parts of page?

I delete "/includes/src/Vishwasnature_Editableproduct_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tabs.php" , than its worked but I dont see the tabs/settings of the categories...

Some dirty solution for me?